# Default value appear in the list "create new item" SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, migration, custom-list

we migrated a database(column name -- id,fname,lname) from eRoom(ECM) to sharepoint custom list..the migration went fine.. but when in sharepoint i navigate to the list and click on the link to create new item .. i get default values in the "newform.aspx" i.e the column id=1,fname=bob,lname=mason -- this is the first row values of the list..
any suggestions?..is this fixable out-of-the-box?

Update : I used a Tool "DocAve"

Comment: Please explain how the data was migrated into SharePoint.  For example, some sort of migration tool?  Or did you simply do an export into a file (such as .csv) and then import that into SharePoint using the Import Spreadsheet or perhaps the Custom List in Datasheet View?

Comment: I'd suggest contacting them about this.  I'll send out a tweet about this and link to this question, hopefully, you will get a response.

Comment: Also, can you clarify in the question what you are seeing in the NewForm.aspx?  Are you seeing the correct field names?  Are you seeing the default values?  If you are simply seeing default values, I imagine it's able to be fixed by simply editing each of the fields in the SharePoint list columns (List Settings > then click each field, scroll down to the "default value" setting)

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! Please direct your inquiry to support@avepoint.com and we will be more than happy to help resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi Brian That was it..i just had to remove the default values from each of the column in the list settings..Thanks a ton!

Comment: Closed because this is about a third-party tool. Thanks @Franklin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply seeing default values, I imagine it's able to be fixed by simply editing each of the fields in the SharePoint list columns (List Settings > then click each field, scroll down to the "default value" setting).